# jquery datepicker does not work on appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to make all original and appended elements as a date picker but only the original works

I tried this code but next line of inputs appears just as a normal input not a jquery datepicker hope you can find a solution thanks.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".inputdate").datepicker({


    });

    $(".samplebtn").click(function(){

        $(".samplediv").append("<input class='inputdate' type='text' name='date'>");

    });

});

</script>

<body>
    <div class="samplediv">
        <input class="inputdate" type="text" name="date">
    </div>
    <button class="samplebtn">Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After bind dynamic item re initialize date picker.

```
$(".samplebtn").click(function() {
    $(".samplediv").append("<input class='inputdate' type='text' name='date'>");
    $('.samplediv').find(".inputdate").datepicker({

    });
});
```

Comment: this will work without any problem, but I think this is harsh without `promise()` and `done()` for append or DOM elements modification, especially when it's a huge modification.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach `.datepicker()` to those new elements.
Try this for your `.append()` script:

```
$(".samplediv")
.append("<input class='inputdate' type='text' name='date'>")
.promise()
.done(function() {
    $(this).find('.inputdate').datepicker({ ... });
});
```

Hope this help. :D

Comment: where do i copy this code? inside the click function of append?

Comment: you just need to change your `$(".samplediv").append("<input class='inputdate' type='text' name='date'>");` line with my script above :D then it'll be inside your `$(".samplebtn").click(function(){`